# How to convert any content like text editor in wp

Tags: php, wordpress, text

In wp when we going to write post_content, "text" editor convert this post_content another format.

How can I convert any content to like text-editor by function

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, would you please help me by solved my problem?

Comment: Read my comment and the linked information. Additionally, StackOverflow is a question and answer site. Don't ask people here to write code for you, especially if you don't provide an example of what you already tried but didn't work.

Comment: My problem is solved